# cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't called after reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

As the [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW40) said,

> Reloading a row causes the table view to ask its data source for a new
>   cell for that row.

I combine UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    if (self.tableView.isEditing) 
    {
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    [self updateTabItemBadge];
    [self.noDataView setHidden:![self isNoData]];

    WXINFO(@"controllerDidChangeContent");
}
```

Between the above two functions, I reload the target cell:

[image]

```
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
        if (indexPath) {
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        }
```

[image]

I set a breakpoint at Line1563, to check that the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` has been called, but after that, `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` wasn't called.

So, my cell could not be updated.

Somebody can tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: Reloading the target cell?  That's something that I have never heard of.  Not even in Visual Basic...

Comment: The method where you're calling `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` is `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`?

Comment: @leoformaggio yes, of course.

Comment: @TBlue the target cell is the cell at the indexPath.

Comment: might be silly, but tableView is actually pointing to the target tableView? Put an `NSAssert(tableView, @"No Tableview!");` inside the `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:` case to make sure.

Comment: Is the row at the indexPath currently visible on the screen when you send `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`?

Comment: did you find any solution for this? i am fighting this issue all day.

Comment: @shelll not yet, sorry... I forgot the problem long ago.

Comment: 1563? You should consider refactor that class.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: between controllerWillChangeContent & controllerDidChangeContent, there are `beginUpdates ` & `endUpdates `

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check by reloading the tableview using [tableView reloadData]?

If you want only one row to be updated without reloading the table, please check the 'indexPath' type. It should be NSIndexPath.

Comment: The `lldb` print is showing that `indexPath` is a `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: This API works for me. One possible reason that I observed is that cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called when indexPath is nil.

Comment: Or, in your code there is self.tableView and tableView. Could you try using self.tableView while reloading the rows. There is a possibility that tableView is not mapped to the controller's tableView.

Comment: @Anand Please look at the console output.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way I've found to do this is by using an animation other than none. If any other animation is specified, the reload happens correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around I did, but it did the job.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle:
    UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
            if itemDetailDict.count - 1 <= 0 {
                self.mainTable.beginUpdates()
                let cellOne = self.mainTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
                cellOne?.textLabel?.text = "There are no items."
                self.mainTable.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                self.mainTable.endUpdates()
            } else {
                self.mainTable.beginUpdates()
                let removeKey = Array(itemDetailDict.keys)[indexPath.row]
                itemDetailDict.removeValue(forKey: removeKey)
                mainTable.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                self.mainTable.endUpdates()
            }
        }
    }
```

Essentially on the delete row function I wanted the user to be able to delete the row, but when only one row remained, I wanted to show a default message in the cell of the tableview.

To do this, I updated the datasource, and when there was no more data in the dictionary, I updated the cell to display the text, reloaded the cell, then called endUpdating on my tableview.

I hope this helps.